# "Rise in" vs. "rise of"

Tags: word-choice, prepositions, collocation

What’s the difference between "rise in" and "rise of"? Specifically, I am looking at the sentence:

> The rise __ juvenile crime is attributed to three factors.

Which preposition should I choose?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The rise **in** juvenile crime is attributed to three factors.

This indicates that there has been an increase and has a reasonably neutral connotation.

> The rise *of* juvenile crime is attributed to three factors.

This could indicate simply that there has been an increase, but also applies some anthropomorphism or, at least, animation to the object.

Comment: To me, *rise of* need not even mean an increase; it can mean becoming prominent for some other reason.